# reading a line from stdin until a signal is sent

Tags: c, printf, signals, stdin, sigint

I want to write some code that takes input from stdin, and prints the input on the next line, until a signal is sent, the signal being SIGINT in this case. So far I have this code which just prints a message when SIGINT is sent:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>

bool signalSent = false;    

void flag(int signal) { 
    signalSent = true;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    struct sigaction sa;
    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));
    sa.sa_handler = flag;   
    sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, 0);
    while (true) {
        while (!signalSent) {
            usleep(500000);
        }
        printf("signal sent\n");
    signalSent = false;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I tried using fgets() to get the input from stdin and print to stdout, but when I enter ^C (SIGINT) I have to press enter, but I want it to send the message `("signal sent\n");` as soon as it is pressed like the code I currently have. Code using fgets():

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>

bool signalSent = false;    

void flag(int signal) { 
    signalSent = true;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    struct sigaction sa;
    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));
    sa.sa_handler = flag;   
    sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, 0);
    while (true) {
        while (!signalSent) {
            char buffer[80];
            char* t = fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
            printf("%s", t);
            fflush(stdout);

        }
        printf("signal sent\n");
    signalSent = false;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output from code:

[image]

For reference I want my output to look like the picture below. Im very new to using signals in C as well.

[image]

Comment: "*I tried using fgets()*". Please show that actual code.

Comment: @kaylum code now shown

Comment: `sig_atomic_t` comes to mind ...

Answer (score 0):

As detailed in the manual pages for [`sigaction(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) and [`signal(7)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html), the `SA_RESTART` flag causes certain system calls, including [`read(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html), to automatically restart after the signal handler has ended.

It seems that you do not want this behaviour.

`fgets` is implemented by way of `read`, and can fail for the same reasons it can. Without `SA_RESTART`, while waiting on input from a "slow" device (this includes terminals), these functions will set `errno` to `EINTR` if interrupted by a signal.

Note that what can and cannot be done in a signal handler is [complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16891799/2505965).

Consider using [`sig_atomic_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/sig_atomic_t) objects, declared as [`volatile`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/volatile), for these types of flags.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static volatile sig_atomic_t signal_sent = 0;

void flag(int signal) {
    (void) signal;
    signal_sent = 1;
}

int main(void) {
    struct sigaction sa = { .sa_handler = flag };

    sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, 0);

    while (!signal_sent) {
        char buffer[80];

        if (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin))
            printf("%s", buffer);
        else if (errno == EINTR && signal_sent) {
            puts("signal sent");
            signal_sent = 0;
        } else
            return 1;
    }
}
```

Example of running this program (<kbd>^D</kbd> to terminate):

```
 $ ./a.out
foo
foo
^Csignal sent
^Csignal sent
bar
bar
hello wor^Csignal sent
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you forgot to actually set the SA_RESTART flag to zero, thus it is semi-random if it is actually disabled or not.

Comment: @MinekPo1 Providing an *incomplete* initializer for a structure causes the missing members to be zero-initialized. In other words, in `struct { int a, b; } foo = { .a = 42 };` the value of `foo.b` is `0`.

Comment: ah, I must have done something wrong when converting the code to c++ then